# How to make python wait untill an ongoing process is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, process, python-os

I am writing a Python script to organize my files in a folder to respective directories. I Want this to run continuously, so I used the `while` loop to scan for files. but if I try to paste a new file in the folder my script is terminating saying that `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. I understand that it stopped because of the process of **pasting files**. Now I want my script to wait until the ongoing process stops

**code sample:**

```
while(True):
    scan()
    #rest of commands
```

So I want the `scan()` function to wait until the process is over

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use try/except statement. If `scan()` function ends with an error then print some message and keep trying. You can also `pass` the exception and go on. Code should be like this:

```
while(True):
    try:
        scan()
        #rest of commands
    except:
        # error message or pass
```

Comment: I tried it, the first file is getting sorted. when I try to paste another file it stays still, not getting sorted.